# Spring REST template - 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-rest

I am using Spring Rest Template inside a Spring Boot Application.

I always get 401 Unauthorized error even though I am passing the credentials.

I am able to access this service by Chrome REST Web Service Client.

Is there a simplified way to access the REST template in SpringBoot.

Below is the code snippet done so far which results in 401 error

```
 private DetailsBean invokeDetailsRestService(UserParam userParam){
    ResponseEntity<DetailsBean> responseEntity = null;
    String url = "https://dev.com/app/identifyuser/";
    RestClientConfig restClientConfig =new RestClientConfig("user123","pass123");
    responseEntity= restClientConfig.postForEntity(url, userParam, DetailsBean.class);
    log.debug("User Details : {} ", responseEntity.getBody());
    return responseEntity.getBody();
}

public ClientHttpRequestFactory getRequestFactory(String userName,String password){
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials( new AuthScope(null, -1), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName,password) );
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
}
```

RestClientConfig class

```
  public RestClientConfig(String username, String password) {
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(null, -1),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
    setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
}
```

Error:

```
WARN c7af55b5-1cac-4db6-a202-202416c27ba4 
 12612 --- [apr-8082-exec-8] o.a.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator    
: NEGOTIATE authentication error: 
No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: 
No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: 
Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
```

Comment: You don't use spring's RestTemplate at all.

Comment: RestClientConfig is different than RestTemplate, the error is due to the endpoint https://dev.com/app/identifyuser/, are you sure with the credentials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authorization issue was fixed with the below code..

Credentials should be passed to a Spring REST Template with the below code:

```
   String userAndPass = "Test:Test123";

   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " +  Base64Utility.encode(userAndPass.getBytes()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue when i'm trying to make call to webservice, this solved my issue:

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("userName", "password"));
restTemplate.postForObject('','',''');
```

Pass the credentials like this, it should solve the issue.

Comment: BasicAuthorizationInterceptor is deprecated , you can use  BasicAuthenticationInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

I used spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE version. then I work below way.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(username, password));
RequestDto requestDto = new RequestDto();
// set parameter 
ResponseDto response = restTemplate.postForObject(URL, requestDto, ResponseDto.class);
```

Or

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
RequestDto requestDto = new RequestDto();
// set parameter 
HttpEntity<RequestDto> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestDto, headers);
ResponseDto response = restTemplate.postForObject(URL, request, ResponseDto.class);
```