# 401 unauthorized : [no body] with root cause in JAVA Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm creating my first REST API using JAVA Spring and when I'm making a rest call to an external API, I get

> 401 Unauthorized: [no body]

I think my problem is here:

```
requestParams.add("Grant_type", "client_credentials");
```

I saw some questions related to this but none well able to solve my problem.

[Spring REST template - 401 Unauthorized error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022461/spring-rest-template-401-unauthorized-error)

[Spring Boot Callable - 401 Unauthorized: [no body]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224688/spring-boot-callable-401-unauthorized-no-body)

JAVA code:

```
public String getAuth(String client_id, String app_secret) {
        String auth = client_id + ":" + app_secret;
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());
}

@GetMapping(value = "/token")
public Object generateAccessToken() {
      String auth = this.getAuth(
            "CLIENT_ID",
            "APP_SECRET"
      );
    
      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    
      String base = "https://external-api.com";
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
    
      MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            requestParams.add("Grant_type", "client_credentials");
          
      ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
              base + "/v1/oauth2/token",
              requestParams,
              Object.class,
              headers
       );        

       return response.getBody();
}
```

Comment: Did you search for `401 unauthorized no body` in your favorite search engine?

Comment: Yes, I did that I mainly saw links talking about the wrong `authorization` header, I saw questions on here as well but the answers I saw have the Authorization set as me but they don't have the `grant_type` that's why I had the conclusion my problem is there @JimGarrison

Comment: Best to ask: the guy from "external api.com" ..much depends on him. But before: worth clarifying: who gets the 401? The rest template (I would rather assume a 50x here)? Or (from accessing the) the `/token` endpoint??;)

Comment: @xerx593 I have this code working in NodeJS and Go, but I'm new to java so I'm making the conversion of the code as I learn java on the fly.  The rest template gets the 401, when I hit the endpoint with postman I get a 500

Comment: I think I found it: `headers` is at an unexpected (argument) position for this (overloaded) method... https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForEntity(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object...)

Comment: To use headers in `postForEntity` see this article: https://www.google.com/amp/s/attacomsian.com/blog/spring-boot-resttemplate-post-request-json-headers%3famp (we have to wrap our request into a `HttpEntity`) ..alternatively/similar: use `exchange...` methods. Alternatively: try to send credentials as parameters (`client_id,client_secret`) not in header ...https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to my own question.

This is what I had to change;

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            requestBody.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    
            HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
    
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                    base +"/v1/oauth2/token",
                    request,
                    String.class
            );
```

Here's the final solution:

```
public String generateAccessToken() {
String base = "example-api.com";
        String auth = this.getAuth(
                "client id",
                "app_id"
        );

        // create an instance of RestTemplate
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // create headers
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        requestBody.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");

        HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                base +"/v1/oauth2/token",
                request,
                String.class
        );

        // check response
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            System.out.println("Request Successful");
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Request Failed");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        }

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.getBody());
        return object.getString("access_token");
    }
```